# Questions on Dictionary Data

Tags: python, dictionary

```
myd = {"abc":11, "def":8, "ghi":10, "jkl":3, "mno":12, 
"pqr":9, "stu":11, "wvxyz":15}
```

I need help on these 3 questions:

1. Write a code that will print the item and the value such that value is the smallest in myd.
2. Write a code that will print the item and the value such that value is the largest in myd.
3. Make two new dictionaries `myd1` and `myd2` such that `myd1` contains the items whose value is less than and equal to 10, and myd2 contains the rest.

Comment: What do you need help with? Stack Overflow does not exist to do your homework.

Comment: These aren't questions, these are demands. YOU write it and if you have *questions* post those.

Comment: Here are some hints: The first 2 have one-liner solutions. The third, 2 lines. Take a look at the "min" and "max" functions, itemgetter, and list comprehensions. It will be good for you in the long run to learn this on your own. Good luck.

Comment: I just want to explicitly say that, while I agree with what everyone else has said here, I really appreciate how @lightalchemist is responding to this. Hats off good sir or madam.

Comment: This isn't homework, just studying extra problems from the book and didn't know how to start these. Thank you for the hints @lightalchemist. Sorry I didn't mean to command anyone to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

here is some hint you can use:

```
>>> myd = {"abc":11, "def":8, "ghi":10, "jkl":3, "mno":12, "pqr":9, "stu":11,   "wvxyz":15}
>>> myd_key = myd.keys()       # will give you list of keys
>>> myd_key
['jkl', 'stu', 'pqr', 'abc', 'mno', 'wvxyz', 'ghi', 'def']
>>> myd_value = myd.values()  # will give you list of values
>>> myd_value 
[3, 11, 9, 11, 12, 15, 10, 8]
>>> sorted(myd_value)              # sort the list
[3, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 15]
>>> myd_key = sorted(myd_key,key = lambda x: myd[x])   #sort the key on value
>>> myd_key
['jkl', 'def', 'pqr', 'ghi', 'stu', 'abc', 'mno', 'wvxyz']
>>> print myd_key[0],myd[myd_key[0]]
jkl 3
>>> print myd_key[-1],myd[myd_key[-1]]
wvxyz 15
```

try last of your own

Comment: Just a comment, try to use proper grammar, it will get your point across better. Also, if you're hinting, hint in a comment, answers are for *answering*, not hinting.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the functions:

```
def max_dict(_dict):
    temp = {y:x for x,y in _dict.iteritems()} #Reverse the dict
    return temp[max(_dict.values())] #Return the max using the built-in max function

def min_dict(_dict):
    temp = {y:x for x,y in _dict.iteritems()} #Reverse the dict
    return temp[min(_dict.values())] #Return the min using the built-in min function

def new_dicts(_dict):
    _dict1 = {item:value for item, value in _dict.iteritems() if value <= 10} #Dict comprehension
    _dict2 = {item:value for item, value in _dict.iteritems() if value > 10} #Dict comprehension
    return _dict1, _dict2
```

Which work as:

```
>>> myd = {"abc":11, "def":8, "ghi":10, "jkl":3, "mno":12, 
... "pqr":9, "stu":11, "wvxyz":15}
>>> max_dict(myd)
'wvxyz'
>>> min_dict(myd)
'jkl'
>>> new_dicts(myd)
({'jkl': 3, 'pqr': 9, 'ghi': 10, 'def': 8}, {'wvxyz': 15, 'stu': 11, 'abc': 11, 'mno': 12})
>>>
```